# Speed Fan - low fan speed can burn cpu?

Tags: cpu

As i can see, with [this software](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) you can set the fan speed. So, if you set it to low, the CPU temperature will grow really high and it can burn in likely 1 hour - is this possible or not and why ?

Comment: If the "burning" part of your question is to take literally, I recommend you to see this other question: http://superuser.com/questions/89271/do-computer-system-units-actually-go-up-in-flames

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to damage your CPU by disabling the fan or throttling it too much. The reason is simply that the CPU will overheat.

Modern systems will shut down before they take damage. At least they will try. I wouldn't count on that in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can fry your CPU with turning down or off your CPU fan...a CPU will always produce heat and you need the fan (or a really big cooling grill) to transport that heat away from the CPU itself.