# Which PSU should one chose? The biggest is the best?

Tags: power-supply

I'm fully aware of PSU's "Active PFC" and that they won't consume the written W all the time. (Makes sense). But now I'm before a PSU replacement (Guys: NEVER buy a Chieftec. Seriously.)

The question is: If one can get a bigger one (in my case 750W and 650W) ... should that person go for the bigger one ? (The difference in price is not much). No, I don't think I'll soon use all that much.

(*Please* help (if you want of course) to make the question more generic if the question is really not OK in this form. I've been wondering about this for a time already. In my case it would be XFX Black Edition Silver 750W and 650W)

(Basically about "which one" I would go with XFX/Antec/something which comes with industry qualified parts. Like Duracell but in a PSU. :) But the performance is a different thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly any computer can survive on 450w, only get larger if you have an impressive GPU set up. I would honestly just buy the cheapest 80+% certified device that meets your needs - manufacturer is not so important (Within limits) to me  as buying from a shop you trust that has good return/warranty support.

I have built and fixed many computers, you can get bad batches with big brands and on top of this, many big known brands are just white label / re-badged smaller manufacturer devices anyway.

Comment: The XFX/Antec PSUs comes with 90%+ efficiency so really, not a problem. Warranty is 5 year. | Chieftec got also 5 year warranty but they won't replace it , only if it dies completely. -.-

Comment: @Shiki - Take it back to where you bought it and say it isn't fit for purpose / it is broken... Should get a replacement or refund without problem, especially if they marketed / sold it with a warranty.

Comment: I would **not** recommend to buy the "cheapest possible" ( [more reasons there](http://superuser.com/questions/89271/do-computer-system-units-actually-go-up-in-flames/89274#89274) ). Buy a quality PSU, like for example from Corsair (which is making low price and good quality PSUs, like the CX 400)). Having a bad PSU can harm more expensive components in your computer, and maybe in your house, think about it.

Comment: @Wil - The problem is when I start the PC its LOUD. And it becomes louder and louder, and if the room is cold, its louder even more. The noise disappears if I put a heavy load on it. Also, it sometimes keeps on going after I shut my PC down. (Only stops (the fan) when I use the button on the PSU). HOWEVER, they would only replace it if it completely dies (ie. the pc wont start with it at all or if it catches on fire..)

Comment: @Gnoupi sorry, you are right so +1 I will correct... I wouldn't buy a bog standard generic PSU, but most 80+ PSUs are only 80+ through certification and generally speaking you do not get bad brands that go through certification.

Comment: Note that the efficiency (80%") varies with load, which is why a 1kW PSU with a low-end computer is a bad idea -- it won't be efficient, and it will be expensive. You generally want your PSU sized to be at 50-80% load, so a ~450W PSU is pretty good for most common builds.

Comment: Got a 450W currently and it is already not enough. 500W is the recommended for my gpu (opened a question about this not so long ago), and yeah I want to add some hardware. | Maybe I should check green PSUs if there are such ones.

Comment: I would not buy the cheap ones, either.  Some years back a batch of RaidMax power supplies--just about all of them blew up taking the motherboard with them and sometimes stuff on the motherboard.  I ended up throwing out the survivors.